# I want to implement CNIC format when country select its CNIC formet will be loaded against their country format in oralce apex.help me?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I have one field for country it have country list and i have cnic field also i want when i choose country its cnic formet will be loaded automatically when we write cnic it will be formetted with their country cnic formet i have table where i have stored a value formet in table against one country like 00000-0000000-0 this now i want when i select that country then its formetted my cnic with given pattern which i have stored in table against that country

i have take one field for cnic and one field for cnic check IN CNIC it may have a query which store cnic value on dynamic action

Select cnic into :P28_CNIC_CHECK from EMPLOYEE where CNIC=:P28_CNIC_CHECK;

but nothing happend anything when i select that country it never formet his cnic pattern which we have already stored

When country select its cnic will be formetted agianst country cnic formetted rules

Comment: are you using any Plugin for the format (i.e. Masking plugin)?

Comment: No i am not using any plugin i will try to use format mask option inside apex for cnic item i have given 99999-9999999-9 formet but it can't do anything

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Apex/JQuery plugin of Format Mask, and the components on your page should look like :

**`Country (Select List)`** - On change of Country -> execute Dynamic Action to set CNIC Format

**`CNIC Format (Hidden Item)`** - On change of CNIC Format -> Execute Dynamic Action to apply this format in the CNIC field(there will some function to set format dynamically vary based on Plugin you choose).

**`CNIC Number (Number/Text Field)`**

Make sure your Dynamic Actions are 'Fire On Page Load/Initialization' => 'True'.

Feel free to let us know if you stuck at any point or need any other clarification/help in this regards.

Comment: Whatever you said we have already tried let me know the best solution for all countries if i select some country his formetted mask will be reflect over cnic field